# Are raised beds considered a change of grading?

Tags: raised-beds

Are there any permits required? What can be done to prevent problems with authorities in this regard?

Comment: This cannot be answered without at least telling us where you live. And it will always depend on local regulation. Contact you're local code office and find out.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like it would depend on where you live and what you mean by raised beds... If you are building a terraced rice patty, maybe it would, if you mean some planters set off with railroad ties, or concrete landscaping block... Probably not; but check your local ordinances.

Comment: I have not found any bylaw about it in my township. However, the province has strict rules about grading. 

I would think that putting up a raised bed (maybe a foot or two) should not really change drainage or surface water flow.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @Grady Player. This question is very local.  Cities across the world have vastly different regulations. Ask yourself these questions:

- is where you want to build the bed your property? (Condo's anyone?)
- does it change the drainage in any way?
- will it change the amount of sunlight any neighbours might receive?
- is it structurally safe and can you prove it?  I'm thinking of a raised bed on a rooftop where the static load must be assessed against what the roof can hold up.
- is where you want to build it going to affect access of other parties. (right of way, shared driveways)

It's always a good idea to consult your local authorities. In my city they have a phone line staffed with people paid to answer questions like this.

Comment: I would not think it changes the drainage. It is not something like a retaining wall, but rather for  convenience and beauty. The yard is basically straight (baring the necessary grading away from the house). The is nothing structurally I want to do except of putting topsoil inside a wooden case with a meshed metal net underneath to prevent rodent go into the bed and get potatoes, asparagus, or whatever I want to grow there. Due to the raised bed, the soil will get also more air and hence it is better for the plants.

I guess, best thing is to talk with the township clerk.